# Select only latest results for every unique foreign key

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

```
class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = DecimalField()
```

Have model where stored amounts for many products on many date(date may be in future time).

> Example:
>   on 1.01.2013  - Product1 amount  10$  (i.e. this value
>   from 1.01 to 11.01)
>  on 12.01.2013  - Product1 amount  12$
>  on
>   10.05.2013  - Product1 amount  17$
>  on 11.06.2013  - Product1 amount  14$
>
> on 18.02.2013  - Product2 amount  3$
>  on 12.06.2013  - Product2
>   amount  15$
>
> on 25.04.2013  - Product3 amount  11$
>  on 17.06.2013  - Product3
>   amount  13$

DB Backend-MySQL

How may select select **actual** amount(and date entered of this amount) for every product with date <= current_date and amount value in user-entered range
For ex. on date 14.05.2013 and amount range 10-20$
need result with only two objects in queryset:

```
Product1   10.05.2013  17$
Product3   25.04.2013  11$
```

UPD. Interested **optimal** solution, not need many SQL queries and not need in code evaluate cycle of all records.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lt(less than) and gt(greater than) querysets for date field.
Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt

```
from datetime import date

products = Product.objects.filter(price__date__lte=date.today(),\
                                  price__amount__range=(start, end).distinct()
```

Comment: [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) is better suited for that.

Comment: This wrong. In this variant i not get latest prices on date for every product. I special write then need only two object in queryset.

Comment: I am edited my answer for your remark, try now.

Comment: Please *serious* re-read conditional of problem. In you variant - it's wrong.

Comment: It one query- but absolutely wrong answer. In  you variant- if on latest date- not price in range- i get previous value of amount. I not need previous amount. I need- if latest amount of product -not in range- then product not in answer. Читайте условие внимательно, фигню пишете.

Comment: Проблема может не до конца понятна, дело в том что если на 12 мая цена товара 10 долларов, а 11 мая цена- 15 долларов, то в случае такого запроса с диапазоном цен 14-16 мы получим этот товар в выборке. А получить не должны, потому что с 12 мая его цена(актуальная) уже 10 долларов. По Вашему запросу мы получим все товары у которых **когда-либо** была цена 14-16.